# Not able to combine data-bind click with tablesorter

Tags: jquery, html, data-binding, knockout.js, tablesorter

I have a simple HTML table which includes some knockout.

In a few TH tags I have a data-bind click event which works as expected. The moment I attached the tablesorter the click event fails to fire. The table sorting works beautifully though.

I have tried using selectorHeaders and selectorSort to try and create sections within the TH to allow both the sort and click event to work together but have simply failed to do so.

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible or am I just being stupid?

Any help would be brilliant. Thanks

-- code example

```
<table id="table" data-bind="sortTable: true">
            <thead id="header">
                <tr>
                    <!-- ko foreach: $root.DisplayHeadings -->
                        <th style="cursor: pointer;">
                            <a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { $root.doSomething(code)}">
                                <h4 data-bind="text: columnHeader"></h4>
                            </a>
                            <span>sort</sort>
                        </th>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>dummy</td>
                    <td>dummy</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

ko.bindingHandlers.sortTable = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(element).addClass('tablesorter');
                    $(element).tablesorter({
                        headers: { 2: { sortInitialOrder: 'desc' } },
                        selectorSort: 'span'
                    });
                }, 0);
            }
        };
```

This is roughly what it looks like. I have been experimenting with a lot of different ways and this was one of them.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Here is updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGsEH/115/), works fine. Is that what you want?

Comment: You my friend are a legend. Thank you very much. I was using an <a href> tag in the TH and removing that seems to have fixed it as per your example. Thanks again!